# velocity profile of laminar flow in a pipe

Tags: python

for a university project I want to compute the laminar flow velocity at 7 points in a cross-section of a pipe. Later we want to use this data for a flow animation.

Inputs of my function are the diameter and length of the pipe, the viscosity of the fluid, the pressure difference and the average velocity.

For the calculation I only need the pressure difference or the average velocity. So I have to set either the pressure difference or the average velocity to False.

Do you have any idea how I can improve the code?

```
import numpy as np


def flow(diameter, viscosity, len_pipe, dp, v_average):
    radius = diameter / 2.
    x = np.linspace(-radius, radius, 7)

    if not v_average and dp:
        dpdx = dp / float(len_pipe)
        v = radius**2 / (4*viscosity) * (-dpdx) * (1-(x/radius)**2)
        vmax = max(v)
        v_average = vmax / 2
    elif not dp and v_average:
        vmax = 2 * v_average
        dpdx = -4 * vmax * viscosity / radius**2
        dp = dpdx * len_pipe
        v = radius**2 / (4*viscosity) * (-dpdx) * (1-(x/radius)**2)

    return dp, v_average, x, v, vmax
```

Comment: Please fix your indentation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this is a good starting point, but some better code organization will help you in the long run

I would first summarize a few main problems I see:

1. Unclear input parameters
2. Ambiguous path execution
3. The most important part is hard-coded
4. Too many output parameters
5. Repetition of code (i.e. violation of [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself))

All of this basically boils down to code organization.  Rather than just showing you a different solution, I think its best to explain the issues:

1. The usage of `db` and `v_average` is such that it isn't immediately clear how to use your method.  It's best if a user can look at your method and see exactly how it is supposed to be called.  Some docstrings would help.  Also, since these parameters are optional, they should be named parameters, not positional ones: `def flow(diameter, viscosity, len_pipe, dp=False, v_average=False)`.  Otherwise they have to pass in `False` to `dp` in order to use `v_average`, and that is less than ideal.
2. Your code will break if someone passes False in both for `dp` and `v_average`.  You want a nice guard up top: `if not dp and not v_average: raise ValueError('You must provide either dp or v_average)`  This makes your code self-documenting, and avoids bugs.  Also, you should have a guard to return an error if both have a value.  That is just as much a user mistake, and will have an ambiguous return value if the two passed in values don't agree.
3. The post important thing in your code is the locations where you want the flow velocity.  This is the entire point of your function: to calculate flow velocity at some points.  However, you have the points hard-coded.  Sure, you want it at 7 points right now, but what if your needs change?  You have to re-write your function.  That's no good.  Just let `x` be an input parameter, and let the user provide it.
4. You are returning too many things as output parameters.  This is basically a violation of separation of concerns.  All you should really be returning is `v`, which is easier if the user passes in `x`.  You don't have to return `dp` or `v_average`.  Effectively, your function is doing 5 things: calculating some x values of interest, calculating `dp` if `v_average` is provided, calculating `v_average` if `dp` is provided, calculating `v`, and calculating `vmax`.  You need a function that does less.

Also, while I don't know much about laminar flows, the statistician/physicist in me says that you are using a strange definition of average velocity: `v_average = vmax / 2`.  I'm going to assume for now that `v_average` doesn't refer to an actual statistical average, but that it has a different definition in your particular use-case.

**Small Changes**

So what do you do about this?  Personally, I think you should just separate this into two separate functions: `flow_from_dp` and `flow_from_v_average`.  Pass in `x`, lose the extraneous input parameter, and return only `v`.  If the user wants to figure out vmax, then make a separate function: `calculate_vmax`.  Similarly, I would make helper functions that can calculate `dp` from `v_average` and vice-versa.  Having more functions that do less is actually a good thing in this case.  Each function will have a clear calling sequence and return only one thing.  That is exactly what you want.  I'll leave actually making that change as an exercise for the reader :)

**Big Changes**

Another option would be to make this code OOP.  I would envision a `pipe` class that has a diameter and length.  You could also have a `fluid` class that has a viscosity and `dp` or `v_average`.  It would then automatically calculate the one given the other.  Your `flow` method would then become bound to one of the classes, or it could be a method that simply accepts a `pipe` and a `fluid` and calculates the velocity at a given set of points.  I'm not going into a crazy amount of detail here simply because I don't know whether or not that might be a useful suggestion for you, as that largely depends on your level of familiarity with OOP.  If you are interested, I would be happy to give an example of what an OOP solution would look like.

Answer (score 4):

I'll start by saying that I agree with nearly everything on @ConorMancone's review. Read that first. With that said...

**Check your math**

I don't know anything about laminar flow. So I looked it up on Wikipedia, and I don't recognize the equations you are using. Maybe you have a special restricted form. Or maybe you're using something that's more advanced or more basic than what shows up on WP. Or I just skipped over the section containing your equation - it's not like I spent a huge amount of time looking.

Regardless, you should check that your math is actually valid - ignoring the whole "implemented in python" part.

Once you are sure your math is correct, please put the name of the equations and their formula in a docblock comment at the start of the function:

```
def flow(...):
    """Compute the laminar flow through a pipe of constant diameter
    using Professor Farnsworth's equation:

        flow = eˣ dy/dx eʸ dy sec(tan(cos(sin(3.14159))) √ ∛ ln e 
        # circular slide rule, CIT!

    """
```

Be sure and use the "official" form of the equation - not a copy of whatever source code you have. Ideally, use unicode characters in your comments to put in whatever greek letters, bizarre symbols, etc. the math requires. It should read like your reference text, if possible.

The idea is to provide a copy of the ideal form, so that you can look up and check it when you're coding.

**Improve your signature**

As Conor points out, your function signature isn't great. What does it mean when I code the following:

```
flow(3.1, 2, 7, 15)
```

Some of this you can overcome by naming the arguments using variables:

```
flow(diameter, viscosity, length, 15)
```

But a better approach is to used named or named-only parameters in your [*function definition*](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#function-definitions) so that the caller spells out some or all of the parameter names:

```
def flow(*, diameter, length, viscosity, velocity=None, delta_p=None):
    pass
```

**Use parameter names that make sense**

According to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viscosity#Dynamic_.28shear.29_viscosity), the Greek letter *mu* (μ) is frequently used for viscosity. So perhaps it makes sense to use either `mu` or `μ` as your parameter name. (Perhaps not: it's not self-explanatory unless your source-code readers will understand it.)

**Explicit is better than implicit**

You are doing a bad job of testing your inputs. In fact, there's two bugs:

```
if not v_average and dp:
    ...

elif not dp and v_average:
    ...

return dp, v_average, x, v, vmax
```

First of all, ask yourself: do my conditions constitute a complete partitioning of the possible input values? In this case, no. There are two other possible input conditions: `not dp and not v_average` or `dp and v_average`.

In the case of `dp and v_average`, all you have to do is pick one branch and execute it! In the case where neither input value matches, you need to raise an exception or provide some default values or something.

Worse yet, consider that **integer 0 is falsy.** That is, when you have a value `x=None` and you say `if x:` it is going to evaluate as a falsy condition. And when you have a value `x=0` and you say `if x:` it is *also* going to evaluate as a falsy condition.

This means that if, for example, someone were to compute `dp` on the fly, like:

```
f = flow(diameter=10, mu=1.2, length=33, dp=abs(p[0] - p[-1]))
```

there is a chance that `dp` could be computed as zero. In that case, your condition would fail, since it checks for dp. You should instead explicitly test for `None`, and be sure your math will survive if `dp=0` is input:

```
if dp is None:
    # No dp provided
```